# Globally exponentially stable point

Tags: nonlinear-system, stability-theory, linear-control, lyapunov-functions

consider this linear, non-autonomic system:

$x_1  ̇=-x_1-f(t)(x_2-x_3 )$,

$\ x_2  ̇= -x_2+x_1$,

$x_3 ̇=-x_3-x_1$

where $f(t)$ is continuously differentiable and satisfies
$0≤f'(t)≤f(t)≤k$ for all $0≤t $

I showed that $x=0$ is uniformly asymptotically stable which lead to that it is exponentially stable by using this lyaponove function

$V(x) = V^*(x_1,x_2,x_3) + f(t)V^*(0,x_2,x_3)$

$V^*(x_1,x_2,x_3) = \frac12(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)$

we can show that:

$\frac12||x||^2≤V(x)≤\frac12(1+k)||x||^2$

$V'(x)≤-\frac 1{10} ||x||^2$

I need to find $C,\alpha>0$ (at least one of them) in terms of k such that

$||x(t)||≤Ce^{-\alpha t}||x(0)||$

but Im having trouble to find them.

can someone show me how to find $C$ or $\alpha$ in terms of k?

reminder: $||x(t)||^2 = (x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)$

thanks!

Comment: Theorem 4.10 in Nonlinear Systems (Third edition) by Khalil has an answer for this case. If you work it out you get $C = (1+k)^{0.5}$ and $\alpha = \frac{1}{10(1+k)}$